# Impresión de Etiquetas Códigos de Barra

Tags: php

Necesito imprimir las etiquetas código de barra de un producto en especifico en un PDF, el numero de veces que se necesite y debe salir en 3 columnas ya que ese es el ancho de la impresora, pero no se como hacer que me reciba el numero que le especifique y imprima solo las veces que le mande.

Agradeciendo de Antemano su pronta respuesta.